# Restrict access to `/proc/myKernelModuleData` only to an app

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I write a kernel module and user-space application. The kernel module computes sensitive information and sends it to our user-space application. Is there a way to restrict access to `/proc/myKernelModuleData` such that only my userspace application can read/write in it and no other application can interfere (read/write)? Is there another way to communicate between the kernel module and my user space application, where my module can authenticate my app before sending data to it?

Comment: I doubt it since `/proc` variables handle permissions like any other file, but curious what others say.

Comment: Also, as for alternative communication methods, this feels akin to any kind of encrypted communication strategies. Tons of literature on the subject.

Comment: Well, two simple ways I can imagine are 1) giving your app a special user/group and checking the user/group of the process trying to access the file; 2) checking the path of the executable trying to access the file.

Comment: SELinux policy is the standard way to handle that, no?